# How do I get IntelliJ IDEA to import maven libraries correctly?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA version 14.1.4 and importing a Maven pom.xml file to create the IDEA project configuration. I would expect it to read the dependencies declared in the pom file and configure the IDEA module to use those as libraries, but it does not; instead it fails to locate (all of) the libraries and therefore does not build. (The project DOES build from the command line using Maven.)

If I open the Project Structure dialog and look at an individual module, I can see that it has no dependencies other than the JDK and "". If I try to add one I find that some Maven libraries appear in the list of "Project Libraries", but none of the ones that I need. If I click "New Library" to add a maven library I can specify the library by name and it will even appear in the autocomplete list, but when I click "OK" I get the error message "No files were downloaded for ".

I tried looking in settings under Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven > Repositories and my local repository looks correct. Furthermore, if I open the maven repository by hand I can find the .pom and .jar files for the package.

I would welcome any suggestion about how to fix this or how to troubleshoot it.

*[Note: to any JetBrains folks who notice this. StackOverflow is wonderful and all, and I hope I get an answer here, but I did spend about 20 minutes trying to post this on devnet.jetbrains.com instead. It would not allow me to log in. I would have left a message about it... but I couldn't log in.]*

Comment: Does right clicking module name in project view and selecting Maven>Reimport have any effect?

Comment: Use `File > Open` and select the relevant pom.xml, this way the project will be created and configured to get the dependencies from maven.

Comment: Bohuslav: No, that has no effect. I suspect that the error is not actually in reading the pom.xml file but in being unable to import the maven library once it knows about it (since that fails when done by hand).

Comment: Vic: Doing that simply recreates .iml again (or the project) with the exact same problems.

Comment: I have the same issue. Hak solution is using maven idea plugin - generate project for old intellij idea (12 or 13) and then open in 14.1.4.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with version 2016.1 either.